# Kong consul SRV configuration

Tags: consul, kong

I am using 0.10.1 version of Kong which supports SRV queries. I am using consul's dns and trying to integrate it with Kong. Looking at the documentation

```
https://getkong.org/docs/0.10.x/loadbalancing/
```

I am not sure how do I specify my upstream_url in kong

For example:

```
# This tries reaching my service on port 80 instead of the port returned by SRV query    
upstream_url = http://ms.service.consul/ms  
# As per the doc I can specify a port and it is supposed to proxy the port 
upstream_url = http://ms.service.consul:8989/ms
```

What should my upstream_url config look like with SRV records from consul

```
 upstream_url = http://myservice.service.consul:{{do_i_need_something_here}}/myservice
```

Will Kong be able to automatically detect the ports where my service is running or am I missing some important point.

Comment: It should pick up the port info. What are the results of a `dig` query for that name?

Comment: It seems that dns_clutser is not taking comma separated values as mentioned in the comment for config. For eg. dns_server = 127.0.0.1,8.8.8.8 fails to resolve my queries. Having just one entry works fine.

Comment: sorry for the late response, but of course that does not work. In 50% of the cases it will try to resolve your local consul provided name on the public Google nameserver ('8.8.8.8') which obviously does not work. Even if Kong would retry the next server, then in 50% of all cases it would have to do multiple queries, which would be bad performance wise.

It's important to note that Kong will retry if it cannot get a response from the dns server, but in case it does get a response which simply states that the name is not known by the server, then that is considered a valid answer.